# How to take out values from 2 different CTE results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 result sets from different CTE selects, and i need to take out the value of 2 columns in first table from the value of 2 columns in second table.

Query description: In first result i find count of total new customers, and in the second result i get the customers that have any sales ( joining the factsales table ) and what i need is to find the count of new customers that dont have any invoices ( revenue made ). So from my logic that will mean the total number of customers from the first result - the total number of customers that have any revenue ( meaning they can be found in the factSales table ). So the count of customers without any revenue are found in customer table, but arent in factsales table. I hope this simplifies my issue and expectations. Thanks for the help provided.

```
        use dwh01;
  -- Total number of new customers
    with cte1 as(
    SELECT 
         d.[Year],
         d.[month],
         case when c.branchid = '1080' then c.customerid end as New_Customers_Per_Month_1080, 
         case when c.branchid = '1081' then c.customerid end as New_Customers_Per_Month_1081
    FROM [dwh01].[live].[DimCustomer] c
    inner join live.DimDate d -- Date join
        on d.DayDate = c.Createdate
    where d.DayDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-12, 0) and d.DayDate <= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) and c.IsActive = 'Y'
    
    ) 
    select
    c.[Year],
    c.[month],
    count(distinct c.New_Customers_Per_Month_1080) as New_Customers_1080,
    count(distinct c.New_Customers_Per_Month_1081) as New_Customers_1081
    from cte1 c
    group by c.[Year], c.[month]
    order by c.[year] asc, c.[month] asc
    ;
-- new customers that have any revenue
    with cte1 as(
    SELECT 
         d.[Year],
         d.[month],
         case when c.branchid = '1080' then c.customerid end as New_Customers_Per_Month_1080, 
         case when c.branchid = '1081' then c.customerid end as New_Customers_Per_Month_1081
    FROM live.FactSales fs
    inner join [live].[DimCustomer] c 
        on fs.customerkey = c.CustomerKey
    inner join live.DimDate d -- Date join
        on d.DayDate = c.Createdate
    where d.DayDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-12, 0) and d.DayDate <= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) and c.IsActive = 'Y'
    
    ) 
    select
    c.[Year],
    c.[month],
    count(distinct c.New_Customers_Per_Month_1080) as New_Customers_1080,
    count(distinct c.New_Customers_Per_Month_1081) as New_Customers_1081
    from cte1 c
    group by c.[Year], c.[month]
    order by c.[year] asc, c.[month] asc
```

Result from first table:
[image: CurrentResult]

Expected result:
[image: ExpectedResult]

Comment: `on fs.customerkey <> c.CustomerKey`  are you sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define any number of common table expression sequentially. Here I have created two cte named cte1 and cte2 first then joined both with `[year]` and `[month]` column and used group by clause to get what you want.

```
with cte1 as(
SELECT 
     d.[Year],
     d.[month],
     case when c.branchid = '1080' then c.customerid end as New_Customers_Per_Month_1080, 
     case when c.branchid = '1081' then c.customerid end as New_Customers_Per_Month_1081
FROM [dwh01].[live].[DimCustomer] c
inner join live.DimDate d -- Date join
    on d.DayDate = c.Createdate
where d.DayDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-12, 0) and d.DayDate <= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) and c.IsActive = 'Y'

) ,  cte2 as(
SELECT 
     d.[Year],
     d.[month],
     case when c.branchid = '1080' then c.customerid end as New_Customers_Per_Month_1080, 
     case when c.branchid = '1081' then c.customerid end as New_Customers_Per_Month_1081
FROM live.FactSales fs
inner join [live].[DimCustomer] c 
    on fs.customerkey <> c.CustomerKey
inner join live.DimDate d -- Date join
    on d.DayDate = c.Createdate
where d.DayDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-12, 0) and d.DayDate <= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) and c.IsActive = 'Y'

)   
select
c.[Year],
c.[month],
(count(distinct c.New_Customers_Per_Month_1080)-count(distinct c2.New_Customers_Per_Month_1080)) as New_Customers_1080,
(count(distinct c.New_Customers_Per_Month_1081)-count(distinct c2.New_Customers_Per_Month_1081)) as New_Customers_1081
from cte1 c inner join cte2 c2
on c.[year]=c2.[year] and c.[month]=c2.[month]
group by c.[Year], c.[month]
order by c.[year] asc, c.[month] asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have two CTEs defined first and later you can join them, as given below:

```sql
-- Total number of new customers
;with cte1 as(
    SELECT 
         d.[Year],
         d.[month],
         case when c.branchid = '1080' then c.customerid end as New_Customers_Per_Month_1080, 
         case when c.branchid = '1081' then c.customerid end as New_Customers_Per_Month_1081
    FROM [dwh01].[live].[DimCustomer] c
    inner join live.DimDate d -- Date join
        on d.DayDate = c.Createdate
    where d.DayDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-12, 0) and d.DayDate <= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) and c.IsActive = 'Y'
    
    ) , cte2 as(
    SELECT 
         d.[Year],
         d.[month],
         case when c.branchid = '1080' then c.customerid end as New_Customers_Per_Month_1080, 
         case when c.branchid = '1081' then c.customerid end as New_Customers_Per_Month_1081
    FROM live.FactSales fs
    inner join [live].[DimCustomer] c 
        on fs.customerkey <> c.CustomerKey
    inner join live.DimDate d -- Date join
        on d.DayDate = c.Createdate
    where d.DayDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-12, 0) and d.DayDate <= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) and c.IsActive = 'Y'
    
    ) 
SELECT cte1.Year
, cte1.Month
, (cte1.New_Customers_Per_Month_1080 - cte2.New_Customers_Per_Month_1080) AS New_Customers_1080
,, (cte1.New_Customers_Per_Month_1081 - cte2.New_Customers_Per_Month_1081) AS New_Customers_1081
FROM cte1 
INNER JOIN cte2 
ON cte2.Year = cte1.Year AND cte2.Month = cte1.Month
```